# JavaFX Populating ListView<E> from Oracle Database value

Tags: java, sql, oracle, javafx

I am doing a project with JAVAFX to populate a listviiew with values from database. i am doing it with Scenebuilder as follows,

MainWindowController.java

```
public class MainWindowController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private RadioButton connRadioBtn;
    @FXML private ListView<MainWindowController> poListView;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

    }

public List<MainWindowController> getPurchaseOrder() throws SQLException{
        DBConnection sqlCheckConn = DBConnection.getInstance();
        Statement stmt = DBConnection.getStatement();
        String listSql = "SELECT DISTINCT VSI.PO_NO PO_NO FROM VW_SUPP_INVOICE VSI";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(listSql);
        List<MainWindowController> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String s1 = rs.getString("PO_NO");
            list.add(new MainWindowController(s1));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and i get this following error,

```
Error:(48, 22) java: constructor MainWindowController in class weltes.finance.controller.MainWindowController cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

please help me what am i doing wrong ? and pardon me im just starting to learn java

Answer (score 0):

You get the error since your `MainWindowController` class doesn't provide constructors other than the default constructor, but you call `new MainWindowController(s1)` in the `while`-loop.

You try to populate your `ListView` with instances of your controller class, which doesn't make sense to me. (I know few scenarios where adding instances of a controller class as items of a `ListView` would make sense, but none of them are similar to your code.) You should use the type of the data you want do display as type parameter of `ListView`:

```
@FXML private ListView<String> poListView;

...

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while (rs.next()) {
    String s1 = rs.getString("PO_NO");
    list.add(s1);
}
```

You could also use your custom class and customize the `ListCell`s displayed in the `ListView` using the [`cellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty), but if only `String`s should be displayed, the default `cellFactory` and a `ListView<String>` should suffice.